# PHP MySQL query: Get category name based on post id?

Tags: php, mysql

`posts` table:

```
id | name              | category_id
1  | Some article name |   3
```

`categories` table:

```
id | name
3  | Some Category name
```

...

```
$sql = '';

$query = DB::query($sql, $post_id);

foreach ($query as $row){
        $category_name = $row["name"];
    }
```

What $sql should contain to get the query done the job?

Comment: a query with the word `join` in it. Cartman would be very upset with you

Comment: `JOIN` the `posts` and `categories` table `ON` `posts.category_id` and `categories.id`

Comment: `SELECT c.category_name FROM categories c INNER JOIN posts p ON c.category_id = p.post_id`. [Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) you can find a tutorial on joins. Throw in a `WHERE` in there yourself, get some practice.

Comment: @Andrew : I think INNER JOIN would be better than LEFT JOIN here.

Comment: @MateoBarahona You are correct, an INNER JOIN would be better off in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.name
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN categories c ON c.id = p.category_id
WHERE p.id = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query="SELECT * FROM posts po join categories cat on (cat.id=po.category_id) WHERE po.id=$post_id"
```